# Targeting an array inside of an array in JSON with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am targeting what I think is an array inside of an array in jSon. I'm able to loop through each set, but can't seem to do anything meaningful with each 2nd level array.

```
  var myObj, i, x = "";
  myObj = {
    "rows": [
      [
        "Provider296",
        "Clicked",
        "Email",
        "2"
      ],
      [
        "Provider296",
        "Clicked",
        "Website",
        "3"
      ]
    ]
  };

  for (i in myObj.rows) {
    x += myObj.rows[i] + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

This produces:

```
Provider296,Clicked,Email,2
Provider296,Clicked,Website,3
```

I want to further break this up so I can end up with a table that might look like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Website</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is your required output? do you want to create a table with last two elements of each inner array?

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I want to do. And the last two elements are predictable and consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ES6,

you can do something like below

html

```
<table id="out"></table>
```

Javascript

```
const obj = {
    "rows": [
    [
    "Provider296",
    "Clicked",
    "Email",
    "2"
    ],
    [
    "Provider296",
    "Clicked",
    "Website",
    "3"
    ]
    ]
}

let out = ''
obj.rows.forEach( item => {
    out += `<tr><td>${item[2]}</td><td>${item[3]}</td></tr>`
});

document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = out

console.log( out )
```

Comment: That worked beautifuly and I learned something new today. Thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myObj = {
  "rows": [
    [
      "Provider296",
      "Clicked",
      "Email",
      "2"
    ],
    [
      "Provider296",
      "Clicked",
      "Website",
      "3"
    ]
  ]
};

const x = myObj.rows.map(([,,third,fourth]) => {
  return "<tr><td>"+third+"</td><td>"+fourth+"</td></tr>"
}).reduce((acc, value) => { return acc + value }, '');

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table id="demo"></table>
```